# Is possible to combine together in same View SwiftUIView and UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Tags: swift, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, swiftui

I am wondering if it's possible to combine a View and a UIViewControllerRepresentable in a same view.
I tried:

```
//Here I declare MyViewController:
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}

struct MyViewControllerIntegrate: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyViewControllerIntegrate>) -> MyViewController {
        return MyViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyViewControllerIntegrate>) {
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello StackOverflow!")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
        MyViewController()
        .frame(height: 400)
    }
}
```

Xcode shows me an error message:

> Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type

Any hints? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in Group (or in some stack, eg. VStack)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group {
           MyView()
           MyViewController()
              .frame(height: 400)
        }
    }
}
```